# CSS href Path from Hidden Filed Value and Extra String

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<link runat="server" href="CSS/Template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

this is my external css link. and also I have a hidden filed in page:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdfExtra" runat="server" />
```

I'm setting a value for `hdfExtra` on `page load`. I need to combine css href with this hidden filed, I need something like this:

```
href="<% hdfExtra.Value %>CSS/Template.css"
```

so we have `Extra/CSS/Template.css` as href. But I do not know how to get it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to direct modify the href on `Page_Load`

First you give an `id` to your `link`

```
<link runat="server" id="csslink" href="CSS/Template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

then on page load you modify the `href` as

```
csslink.Attributes["href"] = RootOfCss + "CSS/Template.css";
```

and we get rendered on page:

```
<link id="csslink" href="EXTRACSS/Template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

you can use a single string `RootOfCss` or use the hidden field value that you ask as

```
csslink.Attributes["href"] = hdfExtra.Value + "CSS/Template.css";
```

The hidden field have a meaning if you change by the user and you use it on post back, if you just take that value from your database, there is no reason to use a hidden field.

### Alternative with Literal

You can use a literal as

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="cssliteral" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Literal>
```

and on code behind on page_load

```
cssliteral.Text = string.Format("<link id=\"csslink\" href=\"{0}/Template.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />", RootOfCss);
```

### Using Public String

You can add a public string on your class, then render it on page, for example.

```
<head runat="server">
    <%=FullLink%>
</head>
```

and on code behind

public partial class PageTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string RootOfCss = string.Empty;

```
public string FullLink = string.Empty;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RootOfCss = "EXTRA";

    FullLink = string.Format("<link id=\"csslink\" href=\"{0}/Template.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />", RootOfCss);
}
```

### Notes

The controls that is inside the `head` is little more tricky because the head is a server side control and you can not easy add string on the link. Other way is to use a literal and direct render there the output.

For example this code

```
<link runat="server" id="csslink" href="<%=RootOfCss%>CSS/Template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

is render by the server as

```
<link id="csslink" href="&lt;%=RootOfCss%>CSS/Template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and we see that the server control is translate the symbol `<` and not let it run as we expect and render the string, so we go alternative and direct change the href from code behind.

The same control **if we move it from the header** and **move the** `runat=server`

```
<link href="<%=RootOfCss%>CSS/Template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

is render correctly as

```
<link href="EXTRACSS/Template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```